# How to capitalize the first character of each element AND delete in an ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist, data-structures

I am trying iterate to capitalize all the first characters of my array list that start with "m" instead of M and also delete any characters that do not start with m or M.
I have tried a code on here which seems to have helped me with removing a couple words but not the one I want and it has not capitalized the words as i need. This is how i have got down some of the codes that I have added

```
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < myNameList.size(); i++) {

        String name = myNameList.get(i);
        String[] names = name.split("\\s+");
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        for (j = 0; j < names.length; j++) {
            if (j != 0) {
                sb.append(' ');
            }

            sb.append(Character.toUpperCase(names[j].charAt(0)));
            sb.append(names[j].substring(1).toLowerCase());
        }
        if (names[0] == "m") {
            myNameList.set(i, sb.toString());
        } else if ((names[0] != "m" && names[0] != "M")) {
            myNameList.remove(i);
        }
    }//end for loop
    System.out.println(myNameList);
```

Results:
Enter the name you want to input
List before Insert
Melbourne Mackay Mermaid Beach Maitland Maroochydore Muwoolimbah Merriwether monkeytown Troydon 
[Mackay, Maitland, Muwoolimbah, monkeytown]
List after Deletions
Mackay Maitland Muwoolimbah monkeytown

after removing

```
            else if ((names[0] != "m" || names[0] != "M")) {
            myNameList.remove(i);
        }
```

List before Insert
Melbourne Mackay Mermaid Beach Maitland Maroochydore Muwoolimbah Merriwether monkeytown Troydon 
[Melbourne, Mackay, Mermaid Beach, Maitland, Maroochydore, Muwoolimbah, Merriwether, Monkeytown, Troydon]
List after Deletions
Melbourne Mackay Mermaid Beach Maitland Maroochydore Muwoolimbah Merriwether Monkeytown Troydon

Comment: `names[0] == "m"` does this compile?  try `names[0] == 'm'`

Comment: Huh?  You want to uppercase e.g. `man` and then _also_ delete it?  Can you add some sample data?

Comment: sorry just updated the post, i want to delete chars that do not start with M or m.
Melbourne Mackay Mermaid Beach Maitland Maroochydore Muwoolimbah Merriwether monkeytown Troydon is the original list.
then i get Mackay, Maitland, Muwoolimbah, monkeytown instead of just removing 'Troydon' and changing monkeytown to Monkeytown

Comment: do you mean any words that does not start with `m`  e.g. `dog` -> `og` ?

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: apparently will not let me use 'm' because the guide i used changed it into a string array and netbeans  wont let me compare a char in a string array

Comment: @ScaryWombat e.g dog needs to be removed entirely as it does not start with M or m.  mug -> Mug and Melbourne remains on list because it already starts with uppercase M

Comment: “Netbeans won’t let me”, oh come on. You can’t blame the tool.

Comment: why not use `charAt(0)` to obtain the first letter to compare, as *you* did some lines before? And removing an element from the list while iterating over it is a bit tricky since it changes all following elements position

Comment: ended up trying (names[0].charAt(0)) =='m' and it allowed me do it, however yielded same results

Comment: still no exact information what is in the list, why you need to split each entry? please **edit the question** and add the input data, output data and expected output

Comment: ok it seems if i removed the else if ((names[0] != "m" || names[0] != "M")) statement and only left the if statement then it seems to capitalize... maybe i should add a whole new method to remove it, since i cant modify to also suit remove...

Answer (score 1):

You can filter the list first, to have only words starting with m/M.
Then capitalize first letter and finally collect to list.

```
List<String> cleanList = list.stream()
    .filter(s -> s.startsWith("m") || s.startsWith("M"))
    .map(s -> s.startsWith("m")
        ? "M" + s.substring(1) : s)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

You should avoid hardcoding "m" as shown below:

**Full example**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> list = List.of("man", "Many", "notM");
    System.out.println(cleanList(list, 'm'));
}

private static List<String> cleanList(List<String> list, char letter) {
    return list.stream()
            .filter(s -> Character.toUpperCase(s.charAt(0)) == Character.toUpperCase(letter))
            .map(s -> Character.isLowerCase(s.charAt(0))
                    ? Character.toUpperCase(s.charAt(0)) + s.substring(1) : s)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

**Output**

> [Man, Many]

Comment: thanks! although I do not understand the delete method, and how to apply it to my case, let me see how I can apply it

Answer (score 0):

A simpler way is

```
for (String name : myNameList) {

    String str = name.replaceAll("^m", "M");  // replace beginning `m` with `M`
    if (str.charAt(0) == 'M')
    {
        newList.add (str);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks! now  I am going to try putting them in different methods, now I just need to know how to remove the first character of every word in the list in a different mothod

Comment: It is not relevant whether this is in another method or not, just pass the `List` as a parameter.  To simply remove the first char, you can just do a `String::substring (1)`  The easy bit of of my code is that you are creating a new List **and** only keeping data that you want to keep.

Comment: do i put String::substring (1) in the else if statement?

Comment: so now you want to store all words beginning with `m` or `M` but you want to trim off the first char - right?  If so please upvote my answer and change to `newList.add (str.substring (1));`